# Confusion with the nameplate of an induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor

Regarding the below nameplate of an induction motor:

[image]

What is meant by?:

> Δ/Y 
>   220/380

Does that mean if delta connected the line to line voltage must be 220V? Im confused also because isnt 220 phase voltage and 380 lne voltage? Could you explain this question  with diagram?

Comment: The motor can be configured to run on different voltages by changing the way its windings are connected internally. If it's delta-connected, it needs a 220 volt three-phase line-to-line voltage, whereas if it's wye-connected, it needs a 380 volt three-phase line-to-line voltage.

Comment: But where on earth line to line is 220V? In USA it must be sqrt(3)*220 = 190V and in Europe is 380V. Where do you think 220V line to line come from?

Comment: Actually, the common industrial three-phase voltages here in the US are 120V/208V, 230V/400V, 240V/415V and 277V/480V. There are supposedly also 347V/600V systems, but I've never seen one.

Comment: @Hearth We use 347/600V in Canada.  It's commonly found in places where you would se 277/480V in the US.  I don't think anywhere in the US uses 347/600V.

Comment: Who uses 220V line to line? please someone tell me:(

Comment: @user1999 Lots of places - China, Chile, Argentina, half of Africa... generally compatible with European 230/415V.

Comment: Europe line to line is not 230 or 220. It is 380V. Line to neutral is 220 or 230V but not line to line.as far as I know (?]

Comment: *Who uses 220V line-to-line?* – The US, if you read 240V within the 255/440V 60Hz range. See **High Leg Delta**.

Comment: On the nameplate it says 220V at 50Hz. US uses 60Hz

Comment: 220V at 50 Hz is what the appropriate voltage would be for delta at 50 Hz. It may not be useful, but 255V at 60 Hz may be marginally useful since there are 240V, 60 Hz, 3-ph services in the US. However, it makes more sense for a 220/380V 50 Hz motor to be rated 263/456V at 60 Hz.

Comment: @user1999 Sorry, thought you meant 220/380.  If you're asking about 220 delta, also a lot of places use that - central and south america, again parts of Africa, southeast asia and the pacific, etc.  Brazil is a big one I can think of where 220 delta is common.  It also exists in France in some places.

Comment: The name plate is just telling you how the motor can be powered in both delta and Y configurations at both 50 and 60 Hz. If you don't need 220 @50 Hz, then just move along and stop acting hysterical about it. Also please note that three phase motors can be powered from variable frequency drives, and the additional nameplate data may be useful to people who do that.

Comment: Many variable frequency drives put out 220V delta, especially the smaller ones where the input is single phase. I don't know how common such would be at that size but this is sometimes very useful in applications like retrofitting smaller machine tools with a VFD to run on single phase input to the drive.

Answer (score 13):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frqZjf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two connection methods.*

The windings on your motor can take 220 V between their terminals.

- On a 220 V 3-phase supply you connect as shown in Figure 1b.
- On a 380 V 3-phase supply you connect as shown in Figure 1a.

Note that in each case the voltage across each **winding** is 220 V while the voltage between the supply terminals may not be.

It is simple trigonometry to show that the 380 V phase to phase voltage is \$ \sqrt 3 V_{p-n} \$.

Answer (score 6):

If you take the ratio of line voltage to the phase voltage for a 3 phase system supply you get \$\sqrt3\$ = 1.732. Now 380 divided by 220 is 1.727 (about 0.3% off from perfect) so this informs that if the windings are Y connected, each winding receives 220 volts from a 380 volt 3 phase supply.

Try this picture of a 120 volts/208 volt set-up: -

[image]

Comment: Oh I got it very clear now thanks.

Comment: But dont you think they wrote in wrong order on the name plate?

Comment: They wrote Δ/Y 220/380 but shouldnt it be more correct Δ/Y 380/220 ??

Comment: No, if you operate in delta your line voltage is 220 volts because the coils are placed directly across pairs of lines. In star, to get the same 220 volts across each winding, you have a line voltage of 380 volts.

Comment: Hmm I guess I need to think about it more

Comment: If you wired it delta across 380 volts you would blow the fuses/contactors pretty quickly unless it was designed to handle the saturation of the core due to excess current.

Comment: To the OP: This is a six-wire motor. All three windings have both ends available for wiring. When the nameplate says delta, it means the user has connected the MOTOR WINDINGS in Delta. When the nameplate says Y it means the user has connected the MOTOR WINDINGS in Y. Hopefully it is intuitive that when the motor windings are in Y, you need a higher line-to-line voltage to drive the motor.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually quite simple.

It the nameplate states Δ/Y 220/380 this means that this motor is designed and can be connected in delta, if the line voltage is 220 volts. If the line voltage is 380 V then the motor can be connected in star.

This comes from the fact, that the the max  allowed voltage per motor winding is 220 volts. In either case the the winding gets 220 volts supply. By connecting this type a motor in delta with line voltage 380 will burn the motor!

When the line voltage is 380V and you want to connected it to delta then the motor nameplate should state Δ/Y 380/660.